Csound : How to concat a string and an integer?
I have a Csound instrument that triggers a new sound every 30 seconds with random parameters. So, a new sound every time.
I would like each sound to be recorded in a different sound file, such as file1.wav, file2.wav, etc.
I tried to increment an integer value and concat this value with a string :
ifile = ifile + 1
Sfile1 strcat "file", ifile
Sfile1 strcat Sfile1, ".wav"
but strcat accepts strings only...
How can I achieve that ?

In that case you can convert your integers to string using sprintf/sprintfk to format strings with integers and strcat for concatenation.
Your code will look something like this:
ifile = ifile + 1
Sfile1 sprintf "file%d.wav", ifile

Refer to this documentation for more information: Csound sprintf doc.
